# Regarding 2D Array in OpenCl kernels

Tags: opencl

How can one find out the size of the biggest 2D array that could be made in an OpenCL kernel?

For example
int anArray[1000][1000]; inside a kernel works fine.
but when I rewrite it for a bigger scenario like 
int anArray[5000][5000] it shows a failed RUN.

Would like to know what exactly is/are the factor/factors that decides the maximum array size that could run successfully.

Comment: can you post the kernel code? is it running 5k x 5k in a single work group, or across many groups? are you using floats or doubles? what device are you running on specifically? (GPU/CPU, brand, model#)

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve this kind of information using clGetDeviceInfo.

The following arguments should help you (depending on how you write your kernel) :

- CL_DEVICE_GLOBAL_MEM_CACHE_SIZE
- CL_DEVICE_LOCAL_MEM_SIZE

Reference : http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.0/docs/man/xhtml/clGetDeviceInfo.html